# My MAMP Pro trial expired, and now my Wordpress install isn't working, any ideas?

Tags: database, wordpress, localhost, mamp, mamp-pro

I've recently downgraded from MAMP Pro to MAMP and noticed that my Wordpress database is gone.

I found this tidbit from MAMP Pro's forum, http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7416

> MAMP PRO 1.7.2 is using this databse:
> /Library/Application Support/living-e/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
>
> MAMP PRO 1.7.2 is using this databse:
> /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
>
> So you can copy your database files of MAMP PRO to the MAMP database folder.
> Stop servers first! Make Backups! Just copy, don't move!

... And that's what I did, but now when I navigate to the local homepage it brings me to the 5 Minute install page, which doesn't make sense. After looking into the phpMyAdmin I noticed that the database "wordpress" exist now with the table names, but missing the content... any ideas?

Comment: I am having the same problem, except that when i check my database in phpMyAdmin, the database no longer has any tables

Answer (score 2):

hi if your mamp pro exired don't b worry just change your system date you get your all lost backup. :) my demo expired on 27 feb an i lost too but i set my system date 21 feb . and i got my lost all DB.

Answer (score 1):

check your wp-config.php file - to be sure user,password and host are correct

```
go to http://localhost:8888/MAMP/ to see if your DB is installed & working
```

usually on mamp default user & pass are : root and host is localhost

Answer (score 0):

Set your system clock to the last time your MAMP PRO was active and it will work again, back up your data